# Grid Layout Widget Sizing Problems

Tags: qt

I use a Grid Layout inside my app. The grid layout I set to some fixed sizes.

```
     myBootGridLayout->setContentsMargins(3,0,0,0);
     myBootGridLayout->setRowMinimumHeight(0,25);
     myBootGridLayout->setRowMinimumHeight(1,25);
     myBootGridLayout->setRowMinimumHeight(2,25);
     wdgBootFeatues->setFixedHeight(80);
```

For the QPushButton I use a size rule:

```
btnSelBootImagePath->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);
```

[image: My grid layout]

But as you can see on the image, the ComboBox and Buttons have the same size but the LineEdit field is smaller. What I do wrong? Is there a trick to bring them on the common same size (Height) like in the QT documentation?

[image: Documentation]

Comment: I have added now a QVBoxLayout, inside this I put first a QHBoxLayout and then a QGridLayout. Now it looks better, but I think on macOS QT has many problems, hasn't it?

Answer (score 0):

In case your question is to understand how to make sure that elements will have the same height, we should consider the following:

1. Layout might not necessarily ensure that some elements will have same height you would like, since it also relies on the size (horizontal and vertical) policy of the element in layout itself. In case you want to have QLineEdit and QPushButton instances to have the same height, you should set minimum height for each of them. Probably, it would even make sense to make the height fixed (i.e. set both minimum and maximum height to be the same values) for such elements to fit your needs, since both of these elements by default have fixed vertical size policy. This is for the reason, since most apps treat buttons and one line text fields in the same way.
2. In most cases, combining QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout and then QGridLayout is not necessary at all, since QGridLayout is much more flexible, and combines QVBoxLayout and QHBoxLayout features in a single layout under the hood at the first place, this it will probably satisfy all your needs (i.e. to represent you elements in a grid manner). Also, construction of UI elements will be slightly faster if less elements will be used.
3. Qt documentation might have such an effect because of the following reason - elements were tested on a different device. Qt does not try to make identical style sheets for widgets' elements across all platforms, thus visual differences will be everywhere. On some operating systems, button height is smaller than text field height by default, and this is completely normal.
4. One approach to make sure that size will get bigger than by default is to change size policy (vertical in your case). Code snippet changing size policy is correct basically. However, size policy is different thing than fixed height across elements. However, if your button and line edit would be in the same row, and both would have minimum expanding vertical policy, probably these elements would have the same height in that row.

Thus, probably to make sure the height of your elements remains the same is to set some minimum (and maximum as well in case vertical size policy is fixed) height through code or Qt Creator. This would be the easiest and least painful from thinking perspective approach. I am not sure if I have answered the question (it looks like that you answered yourself in your own way), but I am sure that I have introduced some thoughts that might come in handy when understanding Qt layouts.